# JLayer mp3 playing several Songs in short time

Tags: java, mp3, jlayer

I'm working on a small game and I have some buttons inside. I want to play a "Klick" sound every time a button gets hit. For this I'm using JLayer from JavaZoom to play the mp3 files like this:

```
    BasicPlayer player = new BasicPlayer();
    player.open(Frame.class.getResource("/sounds/Klick.mp3"));

    JLabel label = new JLabel ();
    panelMain.add(label);
    label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    player.play();
                } 
    }
```

This works out one or two times but then it takes about a second after klicking the button to play the sound. This is really annoying.

Thanks for help!